# Can't create folder "debug" Android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

Hi am presently trying to build my project in android but i keep getting this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Could not delete folder C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\Andriod\World\GATES\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000
```

even when i decided to delete the folder by myself i got this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Could not create empty folder C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\Andriod\World\GATES\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug
```

I then fixed my dependencies to debug thinking that will solve it but got this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
java.io.IOException: Could not delete folder C:\Users\Henry\Desktop\Andriod\World\GATES\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\ant
```

How can I fix all of this mess and there seems to be little of this kind of problems on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried running your IDE as Administrator? I once had the same kind of problem as my Android Studio didn't have admin rights to make changes in C:/. Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is more likely the reverse - that it was run as a privileged account at some point in the past which created files the ordinary account cannot cleanup/replace.  The path in question seems like it should be owned by an ordinary user, unless that is a *different user* than is trying to work there.

Comment: It might actually be better to delete "debug" (and anything else that was created by administrator) as administrator, and then return to using the IDE as yourself.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I only removed package "build" then it all worked

Answer (score 0):

iam just Rebuild a project, this worked from me

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that the other programs do not have the same files opened.