# Android studio 3.0 compile time error BUILD FAILED

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I'm facing this issue after moving on android studio 3.0.

Whenever I try to run after couple of time then this error occurs.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDevDebug]
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'D:\Akash\Final\android_main\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\dev\debug\0.jar'.
Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'D:\Akash\Final\android_main\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\dev\debug\0.jar'.
Error:java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'D:\Akash\Final\android_main\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\dev\debug\0.jar'.
Information:BUILD FAILED in 2s
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
```

Solution is to rebuild or clean then run app.
Because of this i am not able to use instant run feature.

[I have already tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674224/4647628) and it works works.

**But why am I facing this issue frequently like 4-5 times in an hour?**

P.S I do not have admin access. as mentioned [HERE as accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39057265/4647628)

The rest of my projects are working fine without any issue.
You may find this question as duplicate but the previous solutions are not really helpful to me at all.

> Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://XXX.XXX.com/XXX.XXX.com"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    flavorDimensions "default"
    project.archivesBaseName = "XXX";
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file (System.getenv('XXX'))
            storePassword System.getenv("XXX")
            keyAlias System.getenv("XXX")
            keyPassword System.getenv("XXX")
        }
    }
    playAccountConfigs {
        defaultAccountConfig {
            serviceAccountEmail = 'XXX-XXX-account@api-XXX-XXX.iam.XXX.com'
            pk12File = file('XXX-XXX.p12')
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        playAccountConfig = playAccountConfigs.defaultAccountConfig

     ndk {
          abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode true
    }
    productFlavors {

        pro {
            buildConfigField "XXX", "XXX", System.getenv("XXX")
            buildConfigField "XXX", "XXX", System.getenv("XXX")      
            buildConfigField "XXX", "XXX", System.getenv("XXX")
            buildConfigField "XXX", "XXX", System.getenv("XXX")
        }
        qa {
            buildConfigField "XXX", "XXX", System.getenv("XXX")
            buildConfigField "XXX", "XXX", System.getenv("XXX")
            manifestPlaceholders = [facebookId: "XXX"]
        }
    }
    buildTypes {        
        release {
            minifyEnabled false            
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "XXX-${variant.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/XXX'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(path: ':instacount')
    implementation project(path: ':cordova')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.auth0.android:auth0:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'
    implementation 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jenzz.appstate:appstate:3.0.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:cam2:0.7.6'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
}

play {
    track = 'beta'
}
```

Comment: Based on your description, the only thing I can be sure about is that the user who is running Gradle is not allowed to delete the file. In order to say anything more, we would need to see your build script that created the file. It seems strange to me that the script would create files that it is not allowed to remove.

Comment: That's there to downvote this?

Comment: @Jolta I have added build.gradle file. please check.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your question, but often times people will downvote questions where the question is either hard to understand, or if information is missing. Votes are feedback from the community, take it for a learning tool.

Comment: But I believe they should specify reason behind downvote for awareness.

Comment: They could, but they have no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem and solved it.

Try to update Realm plugin to 4.2.0.

See [File handles are not released in RealmTransformer · Issue #5521 · realm/realm-java](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5521)

Comment: updated to 4.2.0 today morning and then didn't face that error till now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one for missing java file as `1.jar,2.jar....28.jar,29.jar`...as soon

in gradle.properties add the following:

```
android.enableD8.desugaring = true
```